# Read iCon of obfuscated apk by Dexguard

Tags: dexguard, apktool

In my application its required to upload apk files and show its information using apktool. All apks works as expected but the obfuscated apks through Dexguard can't read icons. Resources/icons are not present in res folder, they are under unknown folder with wired names.

Any help or hint is appreciated. 
I am using apktool 2.1.1.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer from iBotPeaches.

> The `DUMMYVAL`resources and more are there to allow decode. There has been 0 success of recovering any human readable name. Android doesn't care about resource names, it cares about resource IDs. Dexguard strips the human readable name, so remaking the APK back to human readable format is nearly impossible.